# XML Schema rcase-NameAndTypeOK.3.2.5 invalid

Tags: xml, inheritance, xsd

So, I'm trying to create a schema, whereby I use one schema as a reference and never touch and another schema where I can touch, extend, restrict etc. So the problem I'm having now is that I'm faced with a restraint rcase-NameAndTypeOK3.2.5.

```
<!--Msg -->
<xs:complexType name="Main">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="B">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="B1" type="BType"/>
                <xs:element name="B2" type="BType"/>
                <xs:element name="B3" type="B3-Type"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Types -->
<xs:complexType name="B3-Type">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="BType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="B-4"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Source -->
<xs:complexType name="BType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B-1"/>
        <xs:element name="B-2"/>
        <xs:element name="B-3"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="B1" type="BType"/>
        <xs:element name="B2" type="BType"/>
        <xs:element name="B3" type="BType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I have a work around, and that is removing the restriction in Main. Is there another workaround without removing the restriction in Main? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see another workaround - the problem is that `Main` as defined is not a restriction nor an extension of `B` - being that it can contain an element `B3` as `B` but with one extra sub-element `B-4`.

If you want to have a fixed base schema and then a derived schema with some declaration equal to the base one and some other different probably you should use `xsd:redefine`